# Python object-oriented solution for blending pandas functionality with keras CSVLogger

Tags: python, pandas, class, logging, keras

I'm training a neural network in `keras` and logging the results obtained via `CSVLogger` from `keras.callbacks`. Because my `model.fit()` call is enclosed inside a `for`loop of epochs (an adaptation for mini-batch training), I'm trying to write a wrapper class that blends data-wrangling functionality of `pandas` with `CSVLogger` model logging. My goal is to achieve this using object-oriented methodology by writing a class in my `utils.py` that:

- (before training) initializes a `pandas` data frame where the results for all epochs will be stored
- (before training) initializes the CSV file given a path before fitting the model using the `CSVLogger()` method
- (after each epoch) converts the CSV logger to a `pandas` data frame
- (after each epoch) adds a column the data frame that logs the current epoch
- (after each epoch) appends the epoch-specific data frame to the all-epochs data frame
- (after training) saves the all-epochs data frame to file

Here is my `utils.py`

```
import os
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger
import pandas as pd

class logger(object):

    def __init__(self, data):

        self.log = None
        self.data = data # a pandas data frame    

    def load(self, in_path):

        self.log = CSVLogger(os.path.expanduser(in_path), append=True, separator=',') # ideally I wouldn't have to write directly to temp file

    def log_epoch(self, epoch):

        # convert to pandas dataframe  
        self.log = pd.DataFrame(self.log)

        # rename epoch to iter
        self.log.rename(columns={'epoch': 'iter'})

        # add current epoch value to dataframe here 
        self.log['epoch'] = [epoch for index in range(len(self.data))]

    def append(self):

        self.data = self.data.append(self.log, ignore_index=False)

    def save(self, out_path):

        self.data.to_csv(os.path.expanduser(out_path), index=False)
```

Here is my `train.py`

```
from utils.py import logger

log = logger.data(pd.DataFrame())

for epoch in range(len(num_epochs)):

    log_ep = logger.load(path_1)

    for X,y in data:

        model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0, callbacks=[log_ep])

        log_ep = logger.log_ep(epoch)

    log = logger.append(log, log_ep)

logger.save(path_2)
```

When I run train.py I get this error: `AttributeError: type_object 'logger' has no attribute 'data'`

How do I need to modify the class code to run the script correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a debugger?

I would check the following:

pd.DataFrame() - Check what value you get , as i didn't see the declaration .

in :

def **init**(self, data):

```
    self.log = None
    self.data = data # a pandas data frame
```

I would change to :

def **init**(self, data_in):

```
    self.log = None
    self.data = data_in # a pandas data frame
```

sometimes it cause issues,